# Objective C to Python Serialization

Tags: python, objective-c, serialization

I have an NSMutableArray filled with BeziarPaths. I'd like to serialize it so that its accessible on Python. Someone suggested to me that I can try GZIP + InkML or GZIP +JSON. I was wondering what the best way to do this is. I am also really new to this, so example code would be extremely helpful.

Thanks

Comment: why not SVG? If it's just Bezier Paths, then SVG would be just as  good and much better supported, no?

Comment: SVG seems very interesting. Can anyone refer me to example code showing me how to do it?

Comment: On second thought, I was wondering if there was a binary format that is compatible for both.

Comment: @user1120008, there's plenty of documentation on the Internet for using SVG.

Comment: @user1120008: why would you want a binary format? If it's because of size, SVGZ (zipped SVG) is well supported by many editors. If it's for obfuscation, then you should use your own proprietary binary format; any popular format would have libraries that can access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose what you like most. Both are standards, but JSON is a generic format used for serializing dictionaries and arrays, while InkML focuses on drawing related objects.

JSON support is available in both Python and Objective-C, while InkML has no built-in support in either.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used protocol buffers to great effect in this particular area. It's got very very little overhead and performs better than the native objective C serialization/deserialization(at least on the ipod touch I'm testing for performance with, since it is the slowest device we want to support).

It took me a while to set them up as a newbie in iOS development though(the python side was really easy though).

This blog post really helps: http://nserror.me/blog/2011/06/03/protocol-buffers-and-xcode/

To summarize on how to integrate protocol buffers into an objective C project -- This took me a whole day to piece together so I'm putting it up in the hope someone in my situation finds it useful:

- get protocol buffers from [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- configure/make/make install
- get [this](https://github.com/booyah/protobuf-objc) project(that's git clone https://github.com/booyah/protobuf-objc.git for the lazy)
- autogen.sh/configure/make/make install
- In protobuf-objc/src/runtime there is an xcode project. Open it, build and then close xcode again. It is really important you do this.
- open up your project in Xcode. Go to the "build rules" tab in the target. Add a custom build rule for *.proto files.

The script:

```
/usr/local/bin/protoc --plugin=/usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-objc \ 
--proto_path=${INPUT_FILE_DIR} \
--objc_out=${DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR} \
${INPUT_FILE_PATH}
```

The output files:

```
${DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.pb.h
${DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.pb.m
```

- copy the protobuf-objc project into the same directory you have your .xcodeproj in
- Add a reference to the project in protobuf-obj/src/runtime (just drag into from finder into your project
- Under "build phases" for your target add a dependency on ProtocolBuffers
- Under "build settings" select the "all" view and add the following to your header search paths: ${SOURCE_ROOT}/protobuf-objc/src/runtime/Build/Products
- In the summary for your target, add a link to the .a file generated by the ProtocolBuffers project.
- And that's it, from now on, you just add your .proto files to the project(and to the list of files to be compiled) and you can use protocol buffers